# Zipkin ui can't load the trace diagram

Tags: zipkin

I saw the services had send the trace to zipkin server, and also found the trace result list in zipkin ui, when I clicked one of them to see the trace detail and timeline diagram, but there had no diagram just some duration as the title and json data is ok.

Is there something I can do ?

[zipkin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSzO1.png)

Comment: Which database option are you using?  (i.e. Cassandra, MySQL, Elastic Search or "mem"?)

Comment: The reason this is relevant is that dependencies are only automatically created for MySQL and "mem" (from memory) and so for Cassandra and ES you need to use Zipkin Dependencies to create them.